# New job is different than described during the interview

Tags: software-industry, new-job, career-development, software-development

I'm a software developer with close to 6 years of experience.

I switched jobs because the previous one (big corporation) had become unchallenging, stale, and the manager was unable (or not really willing) to work out any satisfying solution. My new job seemed very good on paper and the interview was one of the most pleasant I've ever participated in.

A few days before I started I was asked whether I would be keen to work in a technology (not permanently or in full capacity) that is completely unrelated to my main experience as they're looking to strengthen one of the teams. Since that technology was something I'm not really interested in working, especially in the long-run, and that technology was not even mentioned in the job offer, I answered that **I'm open to it, but on the condition that it's not full capacity and only temporary**. It seems they took that as a solid yes.

Right of the bat it turned out to be full-time and it's obvious it is not meant to be temporary. I was put in the team with 2 other very senior devs who seem to be happy with the situation. Everyone seem satisfied with my performance, expect me - I don't feel challenged (to be honest the job is boring) and I never wanted (nor agreed) to be put in this kind of project.

On one hand, I feel cheated and I'd like to be moved to a different team that does the kind of work I actually interviewed for and am interested in. On the other hand, I was put there only because **I agreed** so they think it's OK - especially because I quickly caught up and seem engaged (my manager's words).

The problem is that the management knows that nobody would agree to do this full-time if asked openly because they did (internally) and every single developer refused and they're happy I didn't. But I didn't, I just vaguely said I'm open to it and on conditions.

I'm still on my probation. How do I communicate I don't like the situation and would like to be moved to different team? Even though I know the slots (for teams in my city) are all already filled so there's not really any place to go to and the team I'd leave would be severely under-manned? Should I wait till after probation? I'm starting to feel like everyone is starting to notice I'm not really content with the situation.

Answer (score 5):

It is understandable why you agreed, you want to be a team player but unfortunately your company took advantage of this. I would suggest you have a meeting with your manager immediately and put together an action plan, it could look something like:

1. Remind your manager of your area of expertise and that it is not this current technology and that you only agreed to this assignment temporarily
2. Ask your manager for a definitive list of objectives, projects, and /or milestones that would need to be completed in order for the team to be considered stable
3. In writing (email or otherwise) get confirmation that once those tasks/milestones are met that you will transfer to the appropriate team

Unfortunately your manager likely knew what they were doing when they pulled this bait and switch. If they agree to a timeline, hold them to it. If after the milestones are met, you aren't transferred to the correct team and projects you may be in a situation where you need to look for another position outside of the company.

If you do decide to leave for another opportunity, you may want to ask about the specific team you will be working on and what projects you will be contributing to.

Answer (score 2):

I will echo what other say but I suspect this was the idea all along. As you've said the other developers refused so what I think happened is that they first asked everyone who would be able to do the job and they all refused. Then they hired externally (you) and bait and switched you to do this job.

This is what they wanted all along.

So setting goals about how you can be moved to other teams or anything else like that is going to be futile. I've been in this exact situation several times with companies that promised certain things during the interview but then totally ignored them when I was hired. Nothing I said or did ever changed their attitude.

So your choices I see are to stick it out or to unfortunately look for another job. I know it sucks but that's the situation and I've been in the same boat so I can sympathize.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my comment to similar questions [How can I avoid having an interviewer lie to me about what the job will entail?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154806/how-can-i-avoid-having-an-interviewer-lie-to-me-about-what-the-job-will-entail/154811#154811) and [Employer changes working hours](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/152969/employer-changes-working-hours-from-flexible-schedule-to-early-mornings/152973#152973)

You are on probation. Remember that the company is on probation with you too. Straight out of the gate they changed two things: a) what you're supposed to do b) for how long.

And as @Spotted_Flamingo advices are, generally, good. I would not give them the chance to do 2 and 3. Why? Because they can set unrealistic milestones. They can move the goals (they already did it even before you came on board). It's not your job to make the team stable.

I would ask for clarification and dates.

1. Why I am in this team doing this I don't know
2. Why this if full-time and look like permanent when we discussed otherwise
3. When (a final set date) it would be considered for me to be finished with this.

Remember that you said OK under impression that it would be part-time and temporary. If they say "but you said OK", repeat, like a mantra "But on the condition that it's not full capacity and only temporary".

It's their job to hire right people to do right things, if they fail then they see high retention and dissatisfaction in workers.

There is a difference beetwen doing things that you know that are boring and not challenging BUT agreeing to do them and not knowing that and being pushed to do them anyway.